# What is a good Nikon macro lens for medical use?

Tags: nikon, macro, lens-recommendation

I'm an eye surgeon and take photos for patients with squint (crossed eyes) showing the eyes only. I also need to take photos of lid lesions which may be only 3-10mm  I already have the 18-105mm lens. What is the best macro lens for me and my Nikon D90?

Answer (score 6):

Well a few considerations...

- You need something very sharp for what you do, so putting extension tubes on a zoom lens isn't going to give you your best results there.  Zoom lenses, especially with a fairly wide range like 18-105mm are quite a bit softer than a macro or even a normal prime lens.  You want either a normal sharp prime lens and extension tubes or a dedicated macro lens for sharpness sake.
- A dedicated macro lens is going to look more professional and be less hassle, which are both important when working in a professional capacity like a surgeon.
- You're going to be indoors, under artificial light (which is almost always 'dim' compared to outdoors, even when its considered bright inside) - so you'll want:

  - A good working distance so that you don't block your light source with your lens and body.
  - A large aperture so that you can focus in low light and stop down a little to get it ultra sharp but still not be 'slow'.

There's two lenses that generally meet this criteria, depending on your budget.

- [Sigma 105mm f/2.8](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002P19Y4) around $500 US.
- [Nikon 105mm f/2.8G ED-IF AF-S VR Micro-Nikkor Lens](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000EOSHGQ) around $1000 US.

The Sigma is the budget friendly option, but the Nikon is definitely the sharper and better lens.  The Nikon brings faster, quieter autofocus and a stabilization (VR) to help you handhold in lower light.

(The [Tamron 90mm Macro](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00021EE4U) is another popular telephoto macro lens, but its price about equivalent to the Sigma and the Sigma has slightly more reach).

Comment: Re. the light source, perhaps a ring flash would be useful? FYI Kais, a ring flash is a light, usually LEDs these days, that fits around the end of the lens. The light is constantly on as opposed to 'flashing'.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall - In regards to 'constantly on as opposed to flashing' - depends on the kind you buy.  For always on, you want one labeled *Macro* specifically.

Comment: The equipment discussed here is all good, so I'm not going to add a lot to that part of the discussion. What I would suggest *as a costing option* is that you get all cross-disciplinary and look at an *intraoral* kit marketed at dentists -- they are sometimes available without the body, and consist of an appropriate macro lens, a macro flash system (either a ringlight or twin small flashes) and an appropriate case, usually at a very decent kit price.

Answer (score 2):

I own the Nikon 105mm f/2.8G ED-IF AF-S VR Micro-Nikkor Lens and use it on a D7000. It is a great macro lens, all-though a little pricy, with a long Nikon history. It is really sharp and will provide a good working distance for your squint shoots. To capture the lesions in detail you will have to get really close (e.g. 1:1 reproduction). I think this lens will serve you pretty well.

However, the VR (Vibration Reduction, Image Stabilization) is a nice ad-on if you need to shoot handheld or use the lens as a short telephoto (maybe squint shoots), but it will not replace a sturdy tripod for serious macro photography, which a 3-10mm subject (lesions) is IMHO.

Since I have the eyes of a sparrow hawk ;-) and never was at an eye surgeon/specialist, I therefore do not really know how you work and how you might use the lens. But you might also want to think about using sturdy tripod with a proper tripod head and fixing the patients head or provide a comfortable backup so the patients head will not shake. I guess as an eye-surgeon you should already be aware of the latter.

Comment: Thank you all for the great advice.I think the 105mm is my best choice. As for my patients, they are mostly children but I do have many adult patients with squint. It would be hard to keep the child still while taking photoes using a tripod. Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to buy [extension tubes](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2669/what-are-extension-tubes) for your lenses. You can get great results without having to buy dedicated macro lenses.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> [Nikon AF-S DX Micro NIKKOR 85mm f/3.5G IF-ED VR](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/656971-USA/Nikon_2190_AF_S_DX_Micro_NIKKOR.html)

This lens allows a reasonable working distance (about 5.5 inches) and is reasonably priced at about $500.  However, it cannot be fully utilized on FX-format (full-frame) camera bodies.

Answer (score 0):

You might check B&H or Adorama for a new or used 55mm Micro Nikkor. They're usually available for less than $400 new or under $200 used. It's a manual focus lens, which should work fine for your use, and is tack sharp.

Here's some good info: http://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/55f28ais.htm