# Is it possible to do macro photography using canon EOS M100?

Tags: macro, macro-lenses

Can any lens be used along with an adapter to shoot macro using Canon EOS M100 ? Please guide me regarding this.

Comment: It's possible to do macro photography using any interchangeable lens camera, assuming the proper lenses and/or extension tubes, reverse adapters, etc. are available. Macro is all about the lens, not the camera.

Comment: Related: [What are the biggest differences between Reversal Rings, Extension Tubes and Macro Lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/19009/15871) and [Which suits better for hobby usage: extension tubes vs. close-up filter?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/511/15871) and [What's the difference between a regular lens and a macro lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/10569/15871)

Comment: ALso : [What macro techniques offer an alternative to expensive optics?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/9341/15871)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canon sells an EF-M 28mm f/3.5 Macro IS STM lens that would fit directly on your M100, so, yes, macro photography with that body is definitely possible. The 28mm lens would have a very close working distance, though, so if your intended subject is something that might get spooked by the front element of a lens being just a couple mm away from it, you might be better off with one of the other options (e.g. the EF 100mm f/2.8 Macro USM or EF 100mm f/2.8L Macro IS USM) with an appropriate EF/EF-S to EF-M adapter, or as mentioned in another answer, investigating extension tubes, or lens reversal methods (either the two-lens method or an appropriate lens reversal adapter).

Answer (score 1):

Many years ago, I did macro photography with a Kodak Pony 135 -- fixed lens, scale-focus 35mm. I used close-up filter lenses, a calculated distance setting, a small aperture, and a tape measure. Got some nice images of some tiny flowers around 1973. If you want it, you can do macro with darned near any camera.

If your lenses can be changed, you can use extension tubes or reverse mounting rings to fit your filter diameter and camera body.  Whether they can or not, you can use close-up filters, and you can, if needed, *stack* those to get still closer to your subject.

Answer (score 0):

If only used for macro the only advantage I can consider is with 24MP you can crop somewhat more or print a little piece greater...as far as I concern, the additional powerful range will not help as a gauss you are controlling the lighting.